# Mixing commutating Monads

Tags: haskell

I have been reading up on tagless final encodings which gave me a new perspective on mtl. Namely that the concrete monad stack specifies an interpreter for a dsl. This makes it much more obvious to me why the n^2 instances are needed.

There obviously also are commutative monads for which this wouldn't be needed, though. The most notable use case would be splitting up IO so that it'd be easier to reason about and test.

My first idea was to parametrize MonadIO with an implementation:

```
class (Monad m, Monad (Eff m)) => MonadEff m where
    type Eff m :: (* -> *)
    liftEff :: Eff m a -> m a
```

Astonishingly enough this seems to work out fine. It would allow to define lifting instances once

```
instance MonadEff IO where
  type Eff IO = IO
  liftEff = id
instance MonadEff Tracer where
  type Eff Tracer = Tracer
  liftEff = id
instance MonadEff m => MonadEff (ExceptT e m) where
  type Eff (ExceptT a m) = Eff m
  liftEff = lift . liftEff
-- ...
```

And compose effects easily:

```
g :: (MonadEff m, MonadError String m, ConsoleEff (Eff m)) => m ()
g = liftEff (put "foo") >> throwError "bar"

h :: (MonadEff m, ConsoleEff (Eff m), FileEff (Eff m)) => m ()
h = liftEff $ do
  l1 <- get
  l2 <- get
  c <- read l2
  put $  c ++ l1

class FileEff repr where
  read :: FilePath -> repr String
  write :: FilePath -> String -> repr ()
class ConsoleEff repr where
  put :: String -> repr ()
  get :: repr String
instance ConsoleEff IO where
  get  = getLine
  put s = putStrLn s
instance ConsoleEff Tracer where
  put s = W.tell [s] >> return ()
  get = do
    i <- S.get
    S.put (i+1)
    W.tell $ ["putL '" ++ show i ++ "'"]
    return $ "$" ++ show i ++ "(get)"
```

It also allows to use different representations for testing and so on.

```
exec :: IO a -> IO a
exec = id
trace :: Tracer a -> [String]
trace (Tracer f) = snd . runWriter $ evalStateT f (0::Int)
```

So at first glance this seems to work out perfectly while only requiring harmless language extensions and fitting into the existing mtl infrastructure. I haven't seen this before, though, so I am assuming that there is a  catch to this all.

What is the catch?

Comment: I don't see how this helps with multiple layers.  E.g. how do you specify that a parameter `m` has the ability to raise exceptions without spelling out the `ExceptT` layer?

Comment: What would your instances of `FileEff` and `ConsoleEff` look like? I suspect you would have to rewrite them for every `repr`.

Comment: The MonadEff type would only replace the bottom layer.  You also have to rewrite FileEff and ConsoleEff for each repr. The useful thing is that you can add new effects that are embedded into the monad transformer while reusing the MonadEff lifts. So `(MonadError String m, MonadEff m, FileEff (Eff m)) => m ()` could be `Either String (IO ())` or `Either String (Tracer ())` and so on. It also allows for separate implementations for, say, ConsoleEff without re-implementing all of IO. I added example implementations for ConsoleEff to my question.

Comment: You can try to implement this as a library, support common `Reader`, `State`, etc. Maybe benchmark with `mtl` to see how well you're performing. If everything is good  then post on _Reddit_ and get some reasonable critique :)